# Issue with access violation error if input value is too high

Tags: c

I recently started learning programming and trying to do some basic exercises with C. For this program the goal is to print out a repeating sequence of the alphabet with a line break every 40 letters, with a max amount printed of 400 characters.

I'm having an issue where if the user inputs any value larger than 150 the program crashes and gives an access violation issue (0xC0000005). Anything under 150 the program runs consistently and without issues. My assumption is that this is due to messing up somewhere with either my pointers or memory allocation but I can't figure out why 150 is the cut off point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

     char *letters;
     int memory_request, i, j;
     char alphabet[]= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

     printf("How many letters are you going to want?");
     scanf("%d", &memory_request);

     letters = malloc(sizeof(char)*memory_request);

     for (i=0; i<memory_request;i++){
        letters[i] = alphabet[j];
        j++;

        if(j>25){
          j=0;
        }

        if((i%40)==0){
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("%c", letters[i]);

        if(i>399){
             free(letters);
             return 0;
        }

        letters+=i;
}

free(letters);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `j` the very first time it is used?

Comment: `letters+=i;` ups.... why do you do this? It's real bad... never change the value of a pointer that was assigned by `malloc`

Comment: OT: The block `if(i>399){ free(letters); return 0; }` is in principle okay but normally you would instead do: `for (i=0; i<memory_request && i < 400;i++){`

Comment: OT: IMO the exercise would be more "fun" if `letters` were actually used for something. For instance you could turn `letters` into string a print it using a single `puts` call just before you call `free`. Then you should delete the single character printing `printf("%c", letters[i]);`

Comment: `letters+=i;` is lurking at the bottom of the loop... The code loses the address of the start of the allocated block, and will not be able to free it again in spite of attempts...

Comment: Thanks for the other tip. `j` should be zero if don't give it a value right? Also the `letters+=i;` wasn't initially in my code but without it then it just crashes immediately with zero output. Could the fact that I'm messing with the pointer be why it crashes with an input higher than 150?

Comment: Changing the pointer AND incrementing `i` will burn through the block at twice the speed... 150 is actually more like 300... Why are you trying to store these characters anyway? Just output characters from the alphabet, resetting to the beginning as you've done, and output a newline when another counter reaches a multiple of 40... The malloc and buffering is not needed. (Actually, it would resemble the Fibonacci series, compounding in every iteration... 150 is already into no-man's-land...

Comment: "Could the fact that I'm messing with the pointer be why it crashes with an input higher than 150" **yes**

Comment: "j should be zero if don't give it a value right?" **no....** if you don't explicit set it to zero it can have any value. So you need `j = 0;`

Comment: Man I am tired since I put `letters+=i`. That would definitely burn through the whole thing. So now I changed it to `letters+=1` which is still not good but at least now it prints out the whole sequence before crashing.

Comment: @ziggaboogi **Don't change** `letters` !! Just delete that line. What makes you think you need it???

Comment: Also the use of the malloc and buffering was an ask of the exercise itself. Definitely would be a lot easier to just print it out and line break with loops as needed.

Comment: Strip out the malloc and buffering and get the logic working with just ordinary `putchar()` calls. Once the logic is working, you can "upgrade" to allocate a buffer, replacing the putchar()s with writes into that buffer... Do the logic first...

Comment: @Support Ukraine, I'm so confused now. With that stupid line that changes `letters` gone now it works just fine??? But without it earlier it just kept crashing.

Comment: Start any task with nothing more complex than the usual "Hello, World!"... Add 1-2 lines of code and test, test, test. Add 1-2 more lines and test, test, test. With several decades of experience I can honestly say I've met 2 people who can "imagine" a reasonably complex operation, then sit down and type the code. We mortals have to work step-by-step with incremental advances (always checking that we haven't screwed up.) Small, but certain, steps will get you where you want/need to be...

Comment: @ziggaboogi You say: "But without it **earlier it just kept crashing.**" well... in principle it could be due to the uninitialized `j`

Comment: Thanks Fe2O3 and Support Ukraine. I learned a good lesson about not messing with the pointer itself unless I actually know what I'm doing. But I'm still so lost as to why it works all the sudden now when it kept crashing without the pointer changing code earlier. I must have changed something else along the way that fixed it. edit : IT WAS THE J

Comment: @ziggaboogi BTW: Did you see my proposal for a "more fun" implementation where you actually use `letters` for something? Perhaps that will be a good exercise for you

Comment: @ziggaboogi Just to repeat... a pointer that was assigned a value returned from a dynamic memory allocation function, e.g. `malloc` may **not be changed** until after `free` has been called. There is one exception to this - you may change it just after a call to `realloc` and set it to the value return by `realloc`

Comment: OT: If the user wants 90 characters, AND you want to buffer the whole thing, you will need to add to the malloc size extra space for every newline that will be added AND a terminating '\0' to use the buffer as a C string. Don't skimp... Don't write beyond the actual end of the buffer you've got from the OS...